# How to create Console App for ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I don't see an equivalent way to create a console app in Visual Studio for the Mac.  That is, the equivalent of

dotnet new console

When I want asp.net core does not seem to show up as an option. I'm assuming I've missed it since it's kind of a basic thing.

Thanks

Comment: New Project / .Net Core / App / Console Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac you can use the File | New Solution... menu and within the dialog that shows up, select the .NET Core | App category on the side. Then you'll see the option to create a Console Application.

[image: Visual Studio for Mac, New Project Dialog with Console Application option]